# How do I use autofill to match every other column?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use autofill to extend a row of formulas that applies to every other column, as seen below. (Row 7 is a representation of Row 6)

[image: Google Sheet]

If I just select the two formulas and drag to autofill, the autocompleted columns in the formula are `C, E, E, G, G, ...`. I'd like them to be `E, G, I, K, ...`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More easily accomplished using arrays than drag-filling formulas:

```
=lambda(range,bycol(filter(range,isodd(column(range))),lambda(col,sum(col))))(A3:E4)
```

Filter the array of values to obtain only the values from columns which are odd-numbered (corresponding to A/E/G/I/K...), then pass this array into BYCOL to get the sum for each column.

Comment: Thank you, this works, though I had to change the comma to a semicolon (which [seems to be locale-based.](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4271054/change-semicolon-to-commas-in-formulas?hl=en))